# I want to make a report command and send only the report part of the message and ignore arg[0] arg[1] and send arg[3 ] and up

Tags: java, discord

So i want it to do send [sender] has reported [person] for [args[3] and up]

```
if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("!report")) {              
            event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("818967272731050024").sendMessage(event.getAuthor().getAsMention() + " has reported " + args[1].toString() + " for ' + event.getMessage().getContentDisplay()"  + "'").queue();
            event.getMessage().addReaction("").queue();
        }
```

Comment: Can you add more code and be more specific, how are you going to send it , as a message?

Comment: ok i added a bit of extra explanation on what i want

Comment: How are you splitting the message, what is the content of it ?

Comment: so i want it to be "Sender has reported person for args[3] and up, rn it only does sender has reported person for [args[0] and up]

Comment: ok  String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");