# args and up? javasript

Tags: javascript, args

How would I get an arg and up? so like lets say I have something like this:

```
args = ["!say", "pineapples", "are", "cool!"]
```

How would I output the 2ed arg (the one after the !say part) and up? the output would be look like this:

```
Pineapples are cool!
```

So it wouldn't have the !say part

I believe that this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663355/i-want-to-make-a-report-command-and-send-only-the-report-part-of-the-message-and) is asking the same question

Comment: Your JS isn't valid. Is that supposed to be an array?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can use `slice` on the array (assuming it's an array -- using `{}` is for objects, which isn't valid for this).

```js
args = ["!say", "pineapples", "are", "cool!"]

// As an array
console.log(args.slice(1));

// To string
console.log(args.slice(1).join(" "));
```